# How can be POST Audio file and get response WP8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest

i'm trying to POST audio file to my Web Service and get Response from Server. I search on Google but no answer for Windows Phone 8. So please help me.

Update 1 Here my code to try Upload Audio file but have error on server

```
        byte[] buffer;
    void Upload(Stream fileStream)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://localhost:11111/api/SpeechRecognition?dataType=json"));

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        buffer = new byte[(int)fileStream.Length];
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), request);
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        // End the operation.            
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
        postStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        postStream.Close();
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseCallback), request);
    }

    private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = resp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show(responseString); }));
        // Close the stream object.            
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamRead.Close();
        // Release the HttpWebResponse.            
        resp.Close();
    }
```

In server ASP.NET 4.5 have error that line

```
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

Comment: "*but no answer for Windows Phone 8*" then write it first as desktop application. It wouldn't be hard to port that function to WP8.

Comment: i was update my code. Please help me